# Export and run java jar file in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, terminal

I exported a jar file from Springsource Tools Suite, and when I tried executing it in the command line, I always get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

This is the command I input in the jar file though: java -cp ojdbc6.jar oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver -jar ETS.jar

And I already set the main entry point to a class that has main method. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you just do `java -cp ojdbc6.jar -jar ETS.jar`?

Comment: You canon combine -jar with -cp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link on how to set the application entry point in the manifest when packaging your application.

Basically you should have a manifest that identifies the main class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the entry point in the command line via "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" which overrides any specifies in your target jar file. The following should suffice assuming your ETS.jar is setup correctly.

```
java -cp ojdbc6.jar -jar ETS.jar
```

Also oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver does not have a static main method.

Comment: I tried that before, but this exception occurs when I do it.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp ojdbc6.jar oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver -jar ETS.jar
```

1. The class-path is ignored when using the `-jar` option.  Specify the `ojdbc6.jar` in the manifest of `ETS.jar`.
2. What is `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` supposed to mean?

   - If it is an attempt to add a single, unjarred class to the class-path, that is not the way to go about it.
   - If it is intended to be the main class, it should be mentioned in the manifest of the Jar.  OTOH, it sure does not sound like a main class.